# Add a calculated fee based on total after discounts in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, fee

I'm trying to add a fee to my woocommerce cart based on the subtotal after discounts have been applied:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
  global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $percentage = 0.01;
    $surcharge =  $woocommerce->cart->subtotal - $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_discount_total(); 
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', $surcharge, true, '' );

}
```

I don't believe calls like `$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_discount_total()` can be used in an action hook, which is why I keep getting **`0.00`** for the fee.

I also read around some WC values are deprecated and will always show zero, but it doesn't explain why those amounts appear in filters and not actions.

What else can I use in an action to get the same number and add a percent fee to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WC_Cart` object argument is included in `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` action hook. I also use the percentage amount calculation, as I suppose you just forgot it in your code.

So you should try this instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','wc_custom_surcharge', 10, 1 );
function wc_custom_surcharge( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // HERE set your percent rate
    $percent = 1; // 1%

    // Fee calculation
    $fee = ( $cart->subtotal - $cart->get_cart_discount_total() ) * $percent / 100;

    // Add the fee if it is bigger than O
    if( $fee > 0 )
        $cart->add_fee( __('Surcharge', 'woocommerce'), $fee, true );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).*

Tested and works perfectly.

> Note: Also `global $woocommerce;` with `$woocommerce->cart` has been replaced by `WC()->cart` since a long time. The `WC()` woocommerce object already include itself `global $woocommerce;`…

---

Specific update:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','wc_custom_surcharge', 10, 1 );
function wc_custom_surcharge( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // HERE set your percent rate and your state
    $percent = 6;
    $state = array('MI');

    $coupon_total = $cart->get_discount_total();

    // FEE calculation
    $fee = ( $cart->subtotal - $coupon_total ) * $percent / 100;

    if ( $fee > 0 && WC()->customer->get_shipping_state() == $state )
        $cart->add_fee( __('Tax', 'woocommerce'), $fee, false);
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).*

Tested and works.

Comment: your code has helped me discover that get_cart_discount_total is not working with a custom discount type. i have added a custom discount type for gift cards, which does show in the table and back end as a coupon, but is not calculating in the discount total. is there anything i can do here?

Comment: @mnguyen please add the code of your custom discount **in your question** at the end, editing it… when it's done, notify me

Comment: i sent you a message via the form on your profile with this URL attached to identify me. there's a link to a dev environment to see. thank you

Answer (score 1):

the plugin i was using to create coupons was hooking into after_calculate_totals and adjusting the amount afterwards. anything that fires before the plugin wasn't counted into that adjusted total. i was able to call specific amounts using variables in the plugin to create the fee amount i needed

for anyone else who is interested: i am using the ignitewoo gift certificates pro plugin and wanted to create a fee based on the remaining balance after coupons. this is Loic's code with some modifications:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','wc_custom_surcharge', 10, 1 );
function wc_custom_surcharge( $cart) {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $state      = array('MI');

    // HERE set your percent rate
    $percent = 6;
    $coupTotal = 0;
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons as $cc ) {
    $coupon = new WC_Coupon( $cc );
    $amount = ign_get_coupon_amount( $coupon );
    $coupTotal += $amount;
    }


    // Fee calculation
    $fee = ($cart->subtotal - $coupTotal) * $percent/100;
if (( $fee > 0 ) AND  (in_array( WC()->customer->shipping_state, $state ) ))
        $cart->add_fee( __('Tax', 'woocommerce'), $fee, false);
}
```